# Calculate values of rows in a table using previous values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the two tables which are structured like this -

```
table 1
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|1.1|
|  2|1.2|
|  3|1.3|
|  4|1.4|
|  5|1.5|
|  6|1.6|
+---+---+

table2
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  7|  0|
|  8|  0|
|  9|  0|
+---+---+
```

I need to write a SQL query that calculates the populates the `val` column in `table2`, such that

```
val = prev_value^2 + prev_value^0.5
```

where `prev_value` is simply the value of the `val` column in the previous row(`id -1`). So for the first row in `table2` the value of `val` should be

```
val = 1.6^2 + 1.6^0.5 = 3.82
```

This result `3.82` will be used to calculate the `val` for the row with `id == 8` in `table2` and so on.

I tried doing the following,

```
select df2.*
       , power(df1.val, 2) + power(df1.val, 0.5) as sum_val 
from  df1, df2 
where df1.id = df2.id - 1
```

but this returns only one row

```
+---+---+------------------+
| id|val|           sum_val|
+---+---+------------------+
|  7|  0|3.8249110640673525|
+---+---+------------------+
```

which is the correct output but I am looking for a way to get all the rows in `table2` computed at once.

Is there a way to do this in SQL? I am using SQL queries in pyspark.

Comment: If you do it the SQL way I would just create a store procedure fetch all the rows to a cursor and iterate it and do the logic in the SQL script. But a proper programming language would be prefered as always

Comment: How do you define ordering? Are the rows partitioned? If not, how large is the dataset? That does **not** seem like a use case for Spark SQL.

Comment: How about we take the lag of val with a `lag(val) over (order by id) as lag_val` and calculate you result with a rows between unbounded proceeding and current row. But he's, without a partition you'd need a large memory in case the data is huge.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The ordering is defined by the `id` column. The dataset size could be of any size but the typical use case would be about a million records and 40-50 columns(continuous). Could you explain why its not a case for spark SQL?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The use case for the example is out-of-time forecasting with multiple time series. So the data is partitioned by the time-series identifiers.

Comment: Ordering can only be guaranteed per partition and without partitions (just one) you will end up with a computation on a single node. Depending how large the dataset is, it could lead to OOME.

Answer (score 1):

An example for MySQL 8.x.

The query fills all values of `val` field having zero or NULL values with calculated ones.

If starting value(s) needs to be filled they're filled with zero(es).

`id` values may start from any value.

The gaps in `id` values sequence are not allowed (edit recursion part of CTE if you need to remove this restriction).

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( ( SELECT id, COALESCE(val, 0) val
           FROM test
           ORDER BY id 
           LIMIT 1 )
         UNION ALL
           SELECT cte.id + 1, CASE WHEN COALESCE(test.val,0) = 0
                                   THEN pow(cte.val,2)+pow(cte.val,0.5)
                                   ELSE test.val
                                   END
           FROM cte
           LEFT JOIN test ON test.id = cte.id + 1
           WHERE cte.id < ( SELECT MAX(id)
                            FROM test ) )
UPDATE test
  JOIN cte USING (id)
SET test.val = cte.val
WHERE COALESCE(test.val,0) = 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bd194bd9c24c3a784f43124d35126c2)

Comment: Hey Akina, thanks for this query. Is it possible to do this without the recursive queries?

Comment: @ClockSlave This task requires an iterative solution (recursive CTE, recursive stored procedure, cursor). I can't even imagine a non-iterative solution.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. As far as I know, spark-SQL doesn't allow recursive solutions. I need to check that again. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this as an update on a second table is a bit tricky.  Here is one solution:

```
with recursive cte as (
      (select t1.val as val, 0 as lev
       from table1 t1
       order by id desc
       limit 1
      ) union all
      select sqrt(cte.val) + power(cte.val, 2), lev + 1
      from cte 
      where lev < (select count(*) from table2)
     )
update table2 t2 join
       (select t2.id, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
        from table2 t2
       ) tt2
       on tt2.id = t2.id join
       cte
       on tt2.seqnum = cte.lev
    set t2.val = cte.val;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19558151109c9b4f41589d50facbf760) is a db<>fiddle.